# Проблема с MenuBar для AppleTV (TVML)

Tags: menu

Разрабатываю шаблон для приложения для AppleTV на TVML. При включении приложения, оно сразу перескакивает на первую вкладку и вернуться в меню можно только по нажатию кнопки домой, хотя меню должно открываться по свайпу вверх. Код index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
      <menuBarTemplate>
        <menuBar>
          <menuItem documentURL="/templates/jevents/Events.xml" autoHighlight="true">
            <title>Events</title>
          </menuItem>
          <menuItem documentURL="/templates/jevents/News.xml">
            <title>News</title>
          </menuItem>
          <menuItem documentURL="/templates/jevents/Programs.xml">
            <title>Programs and Courses</title>
          </menuItem>
            <menuItem documentURL="/templates/jevents/Settings.xml">
            <title>Settings</title>
          </menuItem>
        </menuBar>
      </menuBarTemplate>
    </document>
```